# how do i update a integer variable in python

Tags: python

for example

```
number = 1
int(input("type a number"))
# types 1 for example
```

how do i get that input to be added to the variable? so i later on can do

```
print(number)
```

and it shows up as 2?

My current code that isnt subtracting or adding balance

```
if outcome is coinflip_side_select:
    print("you won!")
    win = player_balance + betamount
else:
    print("you lost xd")
    loose = player_balance - betamount

print("your current balance is", player_balance)
```

this is the part that im struggling with, because after you either win or loose no balance is added or subtracted from the original starting amount

Comment: Can you not use `number += int(input(...))`?

Comment: Here `+=` and friends like `-=`, `*=` etc are what you need. They're short form as in `x += y` means `x = x + y`

Comment: try adding ` player_balance = player_balance - betamount` and ` player_balance = player_balance + betamount` to update the player_balance variable!

Answer (score 2):

[A function like `int()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/int.html) or `input()` takes an input and often returns an output (called a `return`). That return can be captured into a variable.

In your case:

```
number = 1
num_to_add = int(input("type a number"))
number = number + num_to_add
```

That last line can be shortened to:

```
number += num_to_add
```

And all of this can be shortened by not capturing the return to a new variable, but rather using that return in the addition to `number` as suggested in the comments:

```
number += int(input("type a number"))
```